# Lex V2 Bot execution leads to 500 Internal Errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

Every other bot invoke request ends up in 500 internal error. When this error is seen, the backend lambda function is not being invoked. There are no logs in Cloudwatch. It looks like an issue with LexV2 config. Has anyone faced this issue?

One stack trace:

```
com.amazon.coral.service.InternalFailure: No scaled worker for model.
at com.amazonaws.deepsense.runtime.orchestrator.clients.AbstractRetryableClient.callWithRetry(AbstractRetryableClient.java:46) ~[AWSDeepSenseRunTimeOrchestrator-1.0.jar:?]
at com.amazonaws.deepsense.runtime.orchestrator.clients.LexNLUClient.textToIntent(LexNLUClient.java:85) ~[AWSDeepSenseRunTimeOrchestrator-1.0.jar:?]
at com.amazonaws.deepsense.runtime.orchestrator.recognizer.builder.NluRequestHandler.build(NluRequestHandler.java:74) ~[AWSDeepSenseRunTimeOrchestrator-1.0.jar:?]
at com.amazonaws.deepsense.runtime.orchestrator.recognizer.builder.NluRequestHandler.build(NluRequestHandler.java:49) ~[AWSDeepSenseRunTimeOrchestrator-1.0.jar:?]
at com.amazonaws.deepsense.runtime.orchestrator.recognizer.LexTextRecognizer.recognizeTextIntent(LexTextRecognizer.java:46) ~[AWSDeepSenseRunTimeOrchestrator-1.0.jar:?]
at com.amazonaws.deepsense.runtime.orchestrator.recognizer.IntentRecognizer.recognizeTextIntent(IntentRecognizer.java:97) ~[AWSDeepSenseRunTimeOrchestrator-1.0.jar:?]
at com.amazonaws.deepsense.runtime.orchestrator.recognizer.IntentRecognizer.recognizeIntent(IntentRecognizer.java:55) ~[AWSDeepSenseRunTimeOrchestrator-1.0.jar:?]
at com.amazonaws.deepsense.runtime.orchestrator.RunTimeOrchestrator.handle(RunTimeOrchestrator.java:68) ~[AWSDeepSenseRunTimeOrchestrator-1.0.jar:?]
at com.amazonaws.deepsense.runtimeservice.service.requesthandler.RunTimeServiceRequestHandler.handleTextToTextRequest(RunTimeServiceRequestHandler.java:189) ~[AWSDeepSenseRunTimeService-1.0.jar:?]
at com.amazonaws.deepsense.runtimeservice.v2.activity.RecognizeTextActivity.doRecognizeText(RecognizeTextActivity.java:282) ~[AWSDeepSenseRunTimeService-1.0.jar:?]
at com.amazonaws.deepsense.runtimeservice.v2.activity.RecognizeTextActivity.enact(RecognizeTextActivity.java:181) ~[AWSDeepSenseRunTimeService-1.0.jar:?]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor706.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
```